# "Invalid procedure Call or Argument" when importing access query into excel table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have an excel workbook that has pivot tables and charts linked to a excel table. I want to create a button that when pressed, deletes any data in the table and replaces it with updates data from a saved query in an access database. I have written the  below code but i'm getting an "invalid procedure call or argument" error when i run the procedure. Does anyone know where i've gone wrong?

```
   'button on excel form runs procedure to remove current data in table then 
   'import data from query in MS access database

Sub ImportData()
    Call CleanTheTable("MMPres_MainData", "MainData")
    Call ImportAccessData("qry_MMPres_Main", "MMPres_MainData", "MainData"
End Sub   

   'procedure finds database file and imports query into excel table

Sub ImportAccessData(qry As String, sht As String, tbl As String)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Const dbLoc As String = "D:\AccessPractice\CTDB\CardiothoracicDB_v2_Current.accdb"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim bk As Workbook
    Dim Wsht As Worksheet

    Set bk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Wsht = bk.Worksheets(sht)
    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbLoc)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenSnapshot)

    Wsht.ListObjects(tbl).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (rs)

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set Wsht = Nothing
    Set bk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox ("Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set Wsht = Nothing
    Set bk = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try commenting out lines and see which one raises error.

Comment: Do you have DAO referenced in your references?

Comment: (Should be `Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine object`, where `16.0` is your office version.

Comment: This is just a standard debugging exercise.  Commenting out lines is just one technique, but more useful techniques like local-variable watching, break points, and line-by-line execution can be much more helpful without having to alter existing code.  Calls to `Debug.Print` for tracing execution and displaying values to the immediate window is also a helpful and very effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you had set the necessary library references for `DAO`, the error you get is on this line:

> ```
> Wsht.ListObjects(tbl).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (rs)
> ```

Change it into this:

```
Wsht.ListObjects(tbl).Range(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

also possible:

```
Wsht.ListObjects(tbl).HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

In summary:

1- remove the parenthesis around `(rs)`

2- Dont overwrite the table's header (which is row 1), copy the recordset starting at second row.

3- The method `Range` of the `ListObject` is a bit confusing, it returns the table's whole range, but cannot be fed directly a *"A1-style"* reference, it works more like the the `Cells` method of worksheets.